# Exception thrown when configure Windows Forms application with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to configure my app with a SQL Server database in Windows Forms application. In my `app.config`, I tried to do the following code by I get the exception.

In my code, I initialized my SQL connection like this

SQL Server connection:

```
myConn = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost; Initial Catalog= dbName; 
                           Trusted_Connection = True");
```

Exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.

Configuration:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="myConn" 
             connectionString="Data Source=PC6\SA;Initial Catalog=dbName;"/>       
    </connectionStrings>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: As a side note, you defined connectionstring in app.config, but not using it in your code.

Comment: oh my, I was blinded, sorry about that. This is the reason. Thanks Grant

Comment: @DarkKnight, what do you mean I am not using it in my code? can it explain it?

Comment: @DarkKnight, I declared this in my public MainForm now `string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: @DragonBorn : but you are not using. intentionally?

Comment: @DarkKnight, the reason I am doing the configuration is so that other computer can also load my data from database. Because as you can see, right now I am just  `localhost` which means I can only access my db on my own computer